# program not writing to file but will write to console in c#

Tags: c#, regex, file-io

I have a C# program and it will not write to a file but does write to console, even though the file write line is before console. i have tried several modifications and run through debug as well, and it never writes to the file or it puts one line in the file only

```
// Read the file and display it line by line. 
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("urltest.txt"); 
string myFileName = String.Format("{0}_{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhh"), "-urlcheck.log"); 
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) 
{
Uri myUri = new Uri(line); 
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myFileName)) 
try
{
// create the web request and response based on the url that has been 
// just read from the file urltest.txt
HttpWebRequest reqFP = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
HttpWebResponse rspFP = (HttpWebResponse)reqFP.GetResponse();
if (HttpStatusCode.OK == rspFP.StatusCode)
{
// HTTP = 200 - Internet connection available, server online
// Write status of the URL to the log file
writer.WriteLine("=================================================================     =========");
writer.WriteLine("Status code of returned: OK  " + myUri + "  THIS URL IS NOT     BLOCKED!");
Console.WriteLine("Status code of returned: OK  " + myUri + "  THIS URL IS NOT BLOCKED!");
var _uri = myUri.ToString();
string _catstr1 = catURL(_uri);
//regex to get the last 8-9 items of the line and replace them
Regex pat = new Regex(@"</(.*?)a");
string _catstr = pat.Replace(_catstr1, "\x20");
// Write the Catagory of the URL to file and continue
writer.WriteLine("URL " + _catstr);
Console.WriteLine("URL " + _catstr);
}
}
```

Comment: What type of object is `writer`? You may need to flush it before it actually writes to the file.

Comment: You haven't included any code that obviously does file access...

Comment: don't parse html with regex

Comment: Might think about using a logging library such as "NLog" or "Log4Net" instead of doing your logging manually.

Comment: If the file is created, but empty, it's probably because you didn't close it properly. If you don't close the file, the buffer isn't flushed to disk. If it's simply not creating the file even though there's no error, then you're probably looking for the file in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Most anything that writes out to a file should be either within a `using` block or manually fushed and closed.

```
using (var writer = ...)
{

    // Do your writing

} // <- upon leaving the using block writer will automatically be cleaned up.
```

Note: I'm not a huge fan of `var` but as I don't know what class you're using it at least makes a valid example of code

Comment: here is the full details of function:                                                           // Read the file and display it line by line.
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("urltest.txt");
            string myFileName = String.Format("{0}_{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhh"), "-urlcheck.log");
            while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
               
                Uri myUri = new Uri(line);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myFileName))
                try

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the code for File access, but 99% sure that you didn't close the stream.

Answer (score 0):

call `Flush()` if you want to force output before you close your writer

Comment: There is absolutely no need to call `Flush` before calling `Close`. Certainly not for any of the .NET streams or writers (`TextWriter`, `FileStream`, etc.) `Close` always flushes.

Comment: I didn't say before calling Close() I meant before leaving the writer out of scope or returning from the method.  Everyone is assuming he wants the file to be closed, when he might just want to see the data in the file.

Comment: Then you should change your answer. As it's written, it's impossible to understand that what you really meant is what you said in your comment.